# Passport.js only redirect to failure page, without calling the LocalStrategy

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have a persistent problem with Passport.js in my Express.js small application : whatever I put in the LocalStrategy, I'm always redirected to the failureRedirect, apparently without even pass by the LocalStrategy...
What did I wrong ? And how can I print/display the largest error log to follow the execution ?

```
var express = require('express'),
  passport = require('passport'),
  LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
  http = require('http'),
  path = require('path'),
  mysql = require('mysql'),
  flash = require('connect-flash');
var app = express();

// SQL connexion
var sqlInfo = {
  host: 'localhost', 
  user: 'root',
  password: '', 
  database: 'mex'
};
global.client = mysql.createConnection(sqlInfo);
client.connect(function(err) {
    if(err)
        console.log(err);
});

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('views', __dirname+'/views');
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 85);
    //app.engine('ejs', engine);
    app.use(express.static('public'));
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
   // 1 - Session express
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'secretpass' }));
    // 2 - Init et session Passeport
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());

    app.use(flash());
    app.use(express.logger());

    app.use(app.router);

});

// Simple logger
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  console.log('%s %s', req.method, req.url);
  next();    

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        console.log("localstrategy ---");
        var user = {username: 'w@j.fr', password: 'pwd'};
        return done(null, user);
}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) { 
  // JUST 4 TEST
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) { 
  // JUST 4 TEST
  done(null, user);
});

// Home
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    //check user session value, is logged in 
    if(req.user)
        res.render('menu_log.ejs', function(err, html){

            var data = {
                title: 'Home',
                menu: html
                //req.user['Prenom'] -- à afficher
            };
            res.render('index.ejs', data);

            console.log("index logué");
        });
    else
        res.render('menu_nolog.ejs', function(err, html){

            var data = {
                title: 'Home',
                menu: html
            };
            res.render('index.ejs', data);

            console.log("index PAS logué");
        });
});

// Passport's authentication
app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                   successFlash: 'Bienvenue !',
                                   failureRedirect: '/wrong',
                                   failureFlash: "Email ou mot de passe incorrect." })
);

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){

    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
})

.get('/inscription', function(req, res){

    res.render('menu_nolog.ejs', function(err, html){

        var data = {
            title: 'Register',
            menu: html
        };

        res.render('inscription.ejs', data);
    });
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`LocalStrategy` requires two parameters (either passed as POST data, or in a query string) to exist: `username` and `password`. If you're not passing those two, Passport doesn't even bother to call the strategy handler.

The field names are configurable by passing an object as first argument to the `LocalStrategy` constructor:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField : 'username',
  passwordField : 'password'
}, function(username, password, done) { ... }));
```

Comment: Thanks but even with that it fails

Comment: The specification of the parameters are optionnals, it's only if you want to change the name (here are the defaults one), well it's what I've understand

Comment: @user3154516 yes, it's optional, sorry for not making that clear :) So you're `POST`ing to `/login` with the correct parameters and the strategy handler isn't called?

Comment: When I try to log, it goes to /login, and redirect me to `failureRedirect: '/wrong'` without passing in the strategy handler (well, nothing happens when I ask a console.log in it...)

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/f2ca524783b63c034cee) is a standalone version using some of your code. Save both files in the same directory, run app.js, open `http://localhost:3012` in your browser, and submit the form with username and password filled in. Works just fine for me.

Comment: OK it works ! But I don't know why... My initial strategy handler was
`passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'mail',
    passwordField: 'pwd'
  },
  function(username, password, done) {
      console.log("Appel de check_auth_user");
        return check_auth_user(username,password,done);
    }
));`
and my form fields was "mail" and "pwd". Now I've removed the field specification and put the inial "username" and "password" and it works...
Thank you very much for your time and help

Comment: Use those form fields (with the options object to configure them) works fine for me too.